# When to use Spearman correlation and when to use Wilcoxon Rank sum test?

Tags: correlation, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, group-differences, spearman-rho

I have collected data on 1680 test scores and 1680 participation rates from 7 different courses and 4 different semesters using information from 60 students.

I am confused of whether to use a correlation test or distribution comparison test to analyze the following questions:

**1. Considering that each course has a varying number of students, how can I determine if the number of students affects test scores and participation rates?**

I was thinking of splitting courses based on the number of students in them into 2 groups with a median split and then running Wilcoxon rank sum test on the 2 groups for the test scores of each group, and the participation rates of each group. Does that make sense?

What if I just run a Spearman correlation between the number students in each course and all the test scores and participation rates? It feels like I still have to divide them somehow?

**2. Each course comprises two types of assignments with different proportions. How can I ascertain if the ratio of assignment types influences test scores and participation rates?**

I was also thinking of splitting the courses into 2 groups based on having a ratio >1 and a ratio <=1. Then I would run wilcoxn rank sum test on the 2 groups for the test scores of each group, and the participation rates of each group. Does that make sense?

What if I just run a Spearman correlation between the ratios and all the test scores and participation rates? It feels like I still have to separate them somehow?

Comment: Your first question is a causal inference question, not merely a statistics question. Even so, Spearman's correlation is suitable for quantifying monotonicity, not whether there was in a fully generic sense 'an effect'.

Comment: Oh, your second question is also a causal inference question.

Comment: @Galen So Spearman's correlation can say that there is or isn't a relationship? Which might imply that there might be an effect from the number of students or the ratio of assignment types?


I find that there is no correlation when I test on the correlation between the number of students and test score, as well as the correlation between the number of students and participation rates. However, when I group the data into courses/semesters, there is some correlation. 


How can I explain the correlation among groups? What's the best way to summarize set of correlation coefficients?

Comment: Also, does the p-value for the correlation among the groups matter if the sample size is small (~70)?

Comment: Well, there is Spearman's correlation coefficient which may be used in various testing procedures. The correlation function is not by itself a null hypothesis significance test. But if you use it for a null hypothesis test the null hypothesis might be that there is not a monotonic relationship between the two variables being compared. That isn't the same thing as there being no relationship in general.

Comment: I would personally prefer to use a Bayesian multilevel ordinal regression rather than a null hypothesis significance test. With such a model you can characterize certain forms of statistical dependence among groups.

Comment: Generally p-values tend to be smaller with increasing sample size. I think in your case it will be difficult to identify a scientifically meaningful significance level, so I advise that you skip t he null hypothesis significance testing approach here. Unless you think you can find a meaningful $\alpha$ anyway. (Don't just use something arbitrary like $\alpha=0.05$)

Comment: The best way to summarize a collection of correlation coefficients might depend on what you're trying to show. Personally, I tend to like heatmaps or clustermaps.

Comment: @Galen Why wouldn't group differencing work to see if size is a factor or proportion is a factor for outcomes?

Comment: Your data is structured by the course and semester, and could be common causes of the correlation. You could group the measurements and compute separate analyses, but the results are often worse in terms of standard errors compared to a model that partially pools.